# Why will this SQL code work in Microsoft Access database but not in phpMyAdmin? How should i change it to work correctly?

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

My query is:

```
UPDATE (SELECT * 
        FROM VolunteersFor 
        INNER JOIN Convention ON VolunteersFor.location = Convention.location) 
SET Convention.total_funding = Convention.total_funding + VolunteersFor.donationAmount, 
    VolunteersFor.donationAmount = 0;
```

this code is supposed to add a volunteer's donation to a convention when they are in the same location as the convention, but in phpMyAdmin I get these errors:

static analysis:
5 errors were found during analysis.

1. An expression was expected. (near "(" at position 7)
2. Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 7)
3. A new statement was found, but no delimiter between it and the previous one. (near "SELECT" at position 8)
4. Unexpected token. (near ")" at position 102)
5. A new statement was found, but no delimiter between it and the previous one. (near "SET" at position 106)

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

I don't understand does phpMyAdmin not allow the use of parenthesis? How am I supposed to write a subquery without them?

Here are the images of the tables and their relationship for your reference:

[image: VolunteersForTable]

[image: ConventionTable]
[image: Relationship between the two tables]

Here is the before and after of using the newly suggested query from the user akina:

[before:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ICcU.png)  [after:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kUdg.png)

The desired result should be to have the total funding column in the after image to read 0, 160, 1250, 1250

Comment: Why will this not work..' The sql dialects are quite different - don't expect that code written in one will work in another , sometimes you will need to do a lot of work and you definitely need to learn mysql..

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE Convention 
INNER JOIN VolunteersFor ON VolunteersFor.location = Convention.location
SET Convention.total_funding = Convention.total_funding + VolunteersFor.donationAmount, 
    VolunteersFor.donationAmount = 0;
```

The relation `VolunteersFor.location = Convention.location` must guarantee strict (one row)-to-(one row) joining, if not then the result is non-deterministric, and it **must be wrong**.

If not then you must provide full info (DDLs, sample data, desired result).

[**<kbd>DEMO</kbd>**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9650fad1ac5af5240bae23f91024ae09)

Comment: I tried using your sql code, and unfortunetly it only changed the donation amount of volunteers, but did not add this (donation amount) to total funding.                                          
I will edit the question and post links of the sample data before and after

Comment: nevermind i just figured it out why the total funding wasn't changing; i just posted an answer.

Comment: @CameronWilson I asked You to provide what I asked for, not unuseful photos. Okay, I made fiddle myself. The answer is updated - check.

Comment: @CameronWilson PS. I makes some investigations.. depends on some factors (full DDLs primarily) my query may give wrong result - it is non-deterministic. So two separate queries is more safe solution.

Answer (score 0):

> #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

So, try that:

```sql
UPDATE 
    (SELECT * 
    FROM VolunteersFor 
    INNER JOIN Convention 
    ON VolunteersFor.location = Convention.location) AS T
SET 
    T.total_funding = T.total_funding + T.donationAmount, 
    T.donationAmount = 0;
```

Comment: This query is synthactically wrong. MySQL does not support derived table updating.

Comment: @Akina: OK, that settles it, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If the query gets spit into two parts like this: this will ensure that the donation amount will be added to the total funding BEFORE it gets set to zero.

```
UPDATE VolunteersFor 
INNER JOIN Convention ON VolunteersFor.location = Convention.location
SET Convention.total_funding = Convention.total_funding + VolunteersFor.donationAmount;
```

```
UPDATE VolunteersFor 
INNER JOIN Convention ON VolunteersFor.location = Convention.location
SET VolunteersFor.donationAmount = 0;
```

Comment: If there is no `location` which is present in `VolunteersFor` but is absent in `Convention` then 2nd query may be simplified till `UPDATE VolunteersFor SET donationAmount = 0;`